# Make RDP use machine certificate after it renews

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, rdp

Our machine certificates automatically renew from our local CA.  When that happens, RDP logins fail until someone accesses the console and selects a new certificate in RDP-Tcp Properties > General > Security > Certificate.  Is there a way to have RDP automatically select the new certificate so RDP access is not interrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows Server 2008 R2 there is a gropu policy option that enables automatic certificate request and configuration for remote desktop host: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2010/04/09/configuring-remote-desktop-certificates/